# Editing a particular key value pair in a ini file in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a coniguration file related to an application with key value pair as usual.
one of the variable in [General] tab is xvariable=0.I want this to change like xvariable=1 ie new value to 1.I dont want to use external exes or other programs.kindly help

Sorry for late reply and forgive me as i am newbie to batch scripting as well stackoverflow my initial ini file look like this

```
[General] 
DisableAutomaticallyReconnection=0 
TLUSERDIR=C:\\Users\\Balu\\AppData\\Roaming\\Schlumberger\\Techlog
memoryManagment=-1
[ModuleManager]
lastUsedProfile=TechlogCoreModule_1_Default

[TNotificationService]
Info_balloon=1
Warning_balloon=1
Error_balloon=1
Command_balloon=1
InfoMacro_balloon=1
```

Expected output ini contains only one change in [General] tab i.e.

```
[General] 
DisableAutomaticallyReconnection=1 (new value)
```

other lines of ini will remain as it is.
I have tried three methods(as new to batch scripting)

**Script 1**

```
@ echo off
for /d %%F in (c:\users\*) do ( 
::echo %%F
set filename=%%F\AppData\Roaming\Schlumberger\Techlog 2> nul
cd  %%F\AppData\Roaming\Schlumberger\Techlog 2> nul
where=$(PWD)
:: echo !where!
copy Techlog.ini techlog.orig 2> nul
type Techlog.ini|find /i /v "general"|find /i /v 
"DisableAutomaticallyReconnection" > techlog1 2> nul
echo [General] > techlog2 2> nul
echo DisableAutomaticallyReconnection=1 >> techlog2 2> nul
del /q Techlog.ini 2> nul
type techlog2 techlog1 > Techlog.ini 2> nul
del /q techlog1 2> nul
del /q techlog2 2> nul
)
```

Script 2

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in 
(C:\Users\Balu\AppData\Roaming\Schlumberger\Techlog\Techlog.ini) do (
    set input=%%i
    :: echo !input!
    set input=!input:DisableAutomaticallyReconnection=1!
    echo !input!
    echo !input! >> 
C:\Users\Balu\AppData\Roaming\Schlumberger\Techlog\Techlog.ini.chg
)
ren C:\Users\Balu\AppData\Roaming\Schlumberger\Techlog\Techlog.ini Techlog.ini.old
ren C:\Users\Balu\AppData\Roaming\Schlumberger\Techlog\Techlog.ini.chg Techlog.ini
```

Script 3

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (DataFile.ini) do (
        set input=%%i
        set input=!input:DisableAutomaticallyReconnection=test=1!
        echo !input! >> DataFile.ini.chg
)
ren DataFile.ini DataFile.ini.old
ren DataFile.ini.chg DataFile.ini
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Currently your question I is off topic as unclear. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58928863/edit) your question and clarify what you want and show input data and expected results as well as code attempts if you have tried anything.

Comment: @Gerhard: your solution doesn't take care of sections: ("the variable in [General] tab"), although it works if that's the only `xvariable` in the ini file.

Comment: @Stephan, yes, it was a pre-defined answer with some basics, I was hoping to get OP to update the question so I could determine if it is needed to consider [General] tab as it might be a unique `xvariable` where I do not need to cater for `[General]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a single example script, which you will need to edit, (on line `2`), to define your source INI file.

```bat
@SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
@Set "IFile=C:\SomePathTo\YourFile.ini"
@Set "ISect=General"
@Set "ISKey=xvariable"

@If Not Exist "%IFile%" GoTo :EOF
@Set "SName=[NULL]"
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%# In ('Type "%IFile%" 2^>NUL^|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V /N ""^&Break^>"%IFile%"')Do @(
    Echo("%%$"|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "^\"\[.*\]\"$">NUL&&Set "SName=%%$"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If /I "[%ISect%]"=="!SName!" (If /I Not "[%ISect%]"=="%%$" (
            Echo("%%$"|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IRC:"^\"[;\ \ ]*%ISKey%[\ \   ]*=[\ \ 01]*\"$">NUL&&Echo(%ISKey%=1||Echo(%%$
        )Else Echo(%%$)Else Echo(%%$
    EndLocal)>>"%IFile%"
@Pause
```

*As you've provided very little information and have shown no evidence that you've even attempted this task yourself, I shall not be providing further support beyond this*. Although it's worth me mentioning that in the following, `"^\"[;\ \    ]*%ISKey%[\ \   ]*=[\ \ 01]*\"$"` is actually: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>.